# Sessions in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session

As follow user sessions in Symfony2 , as is the way of working with sessions?

I need to keep the user session by Symfony2 for example, use their name, or that I have some data stored in a database . As recommended me to work ?

im using symfony 2.4

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you can access session via

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set("username", $username);
// ... later
$username = $session->get("username")
```

A more real-life example is one I use to show a banner only once per visit.

```
public function bannerWidgetController(Request $request) 
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    if ($session->get('banner-visited', false))
    {
        return new Response();
    }
    $session->set('banner-visited', true);
    return $this->render('widget/banner.html.twig');
}
```

Then I include this in my TWIG via the "renderController" method.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is a bit hard to understand I don't know if it is exactly what you want but there is already a mechanism included in Symfony2 to store sessions in database.

There is a simple guide you can follow here :
http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html